# Embed interactive 3d objects in a pdf

Tags: plot, 3d, wolfram-mathematica

I have seen pdf files with interactive objects. For example, objects that you can rotate by using the mouse.

I would like to know what such formats can be embedded into a pdf using latex, and how. I have only found documentation for `.u3d` files, but obtaining an `.u3d` file seems rather complicated. I am trying to embed a 3d plot from Wolfram Mathematica, and the only allowed export formats according to [this reference](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/ImportAndExport3DGraphics.html) are `.dxf`, `.lwo`, `.wrl`, `.3ds` and `.x3d` (this last one does not appear in the mentioned reference, but I found out in some other page I cannot remember anymore).

Is there a way to embed any of the previous formats into a pdf using latex?

I tried to convert a `.x3d` file into a `.u3d` file, but that turned out to be a complicated way to go. See the [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/875876/configure-meshlab-to-convert-x3d-to-u3d) I posted on AskUbuntu if you can give any hints on that direction.

Comment: Comment from user https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/193420/bruno-barroqueiro:  Nowadays Meshlab does the job...

Comment: Another option is to use Asymptote to create a prc file, and then use media9 to embed that.  (And if someone wants to convert a one sentence comment into an answer with an example, they're welcome to the reputation.)

Answer (score 1):

probably way to late but for others looking for an answer, you can try the following:
You can use the free software Meshlab to import your plot as a `.wrl`. You can then export it as a `.u3d` file and then embed it using the media9 package. If your plot contains colors make sure to tick the colors option when exporting. With the exported `.u3d` file there is also a `.tex` file with the needed LateX code to run it.